# How to fork processes in R

Tags: r, fork

I'm trying to understand the forking system implemented by R's multicore package. The package example is:

```
p <- fork()
if (inherits(p, "masterProcess")) {
  cat("I’m a child! ", Sys.getpid(), "\n")
  exit(,"I was a child")
}
cat("I’m the master\n")
unserialize(readChildren(1.5))
```

but it doesn't seem to work when pasted in the R interactive console. Does anyone have an example of using fork() with R's multicore or parallel packages?

Comment: I don't think that part of the documentation is meant to be run in a console.  It's showing the syntax problem of a "familiar C idiom."  But I could be wrong.

Comment: `multicore` has been merged into the built-in package `parallel`. I think that we should use `parallel` rather than `multicore`.

Comment: You're right @RandyLai. I spent a few minutes searching for the parallel package before realizing it now comes with base R. It's interesting that the analogous function, mcfork(), is not even exported; you have to run parallel:::mcfork to see it!

Comment: I don't know, is it really necessary to do forking manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `fork` example in the multicore package 'works  for me' ; try `example(fork)`. fork is only supported on non-Windows systems.

I think the equivalent functions in `parallel` are `mcparallel()` to fork and then evaluate an expression, and `mcollect()` to retrieve the result when done. So

```
id = mcparallel({ Sys.sleep(5); TRUE })
```

returns immediately but the process is running, and

```
mccollect(id)
```

will return TRUE after 5 seconds. There is no communication other than the collection between the forked and master process; it would be interesting and not too challenging to implement two-way communication using, e.g., sockets.

Comment: Thanks for this response. You're right: example(fork) does indeed work. Any ideas why? And cool example, but when I run mccollect(id), I get a list with one null element. Did TRUE return for you?

Comment: Maybe this is the simplest example of mcparallel and mccollect: p <- mcparallel(5+5); mccollect(p); You can see the process spin up in a separate terminal with ps -a, and after running mccollect it goes "defunct."