# Is there a method to attach to fork of R in interactive session?

Tags: r, ubuntu, parallel-processing, fork

I would like to offend the elder gods and use `parallel::mcfork` (or something like it) with minimal starting knowledge understanding that there are hidden dangers that may fall on top of my head.  Maybe the behavior I'm hoping for is foolish or impossible; but I didn't think it could hurt too much to ask.

What I want to do is load some data into the workspace and then work with it from two separate interactive sessions with no intent for those sessions to communicate with each other.  I can `parallel::mcfork(estranged=TRUE)` and see that there is another R session with a distinct pid.  What I haven't been able to do is figure out how to connect to it in an interactive session.  I tried using reptyr, but only got a message saying that both pids have a sub-process and I can't attach to them.

Is it possible to accomplish this aim?  If so, how?

For what purpose?  I have a largish dataset that takes a while to load.  Now that I'm using Ubuntu, I've noticed that I can do parallel processing on this large dataset incurring a much lower cost in RAM and time than when I was using a Windows machine (i.e. mclapply vs parLapply).  Now I have this large dataset... but I don't know quite what all I might want to do with it in terms of analysis.  What I do know is that a measurable amount of time is going to pass between my issuing a command and the result.  I'd like to, having loaded the data, analyze the data in two separate interactive sessions so that I can pursue the lines of reasoning that seem most fruitful without having layed out a plan in advance or being stuck waiting and manually monitoring the results of `mcparallel`.  Incidentally, mcparallel provides some hopeful looking options, e.g. mc.interactive, but yields similar errors as before with reptyr.

Comment: Interesting question. But as you state, perhaps foolish. for what purpose (ob quorsum)?

Comment: @Alex; added some rationale above.

Comment: Given your explanation: **sample your data.** Your initial approach isn't a good one

Comment: I'm already working with a sample of the data.  Due to thinness of some variables and the continuous natures of others would prefer not to sample further and/or group observations.  I do, however, appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps there is something to the notion that the question is wrong - I'm still looking at other approaches to the data (those would be other questions).  However, in the interim, for the sake of this question, I'd like to proceed under the assumption that this is a reasonable thing to do (in principle if not in fact) and learn a) whether it is possible and b) if so, how.

Comment: It may be possible. I don't know, and will leave to others. But, if you have *thinness of some variables, etc* I would suggest that you're not sampling correctly. Use an unequal probability sampling method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96091/discussion-between-rpierce-and-alex).

Comment: Maybe you want a variant of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045288/how-to-fork-processes-in-r/23045721#23045721), where `{ Sys.sleep(5); TRUE }` is replaced by the stuff you want to explore?

Comment: @MartinMorgan Close, but it isn't an interactive session, so if I change a parameter / do a costly calculation in one mcparallel session it isn't there when I want to do a follow up.

Comment: It seems almost certain that there should be a way to make this happen via `svSocket` in the host and in the other interactive session (launched via fork); but the implementation hasn't jumped up and bitten me yet.